# I have a light switch that turns on an outlet

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I am installing a ceiling fan with lights in a old house. Theres a light switch that turns off the outlet. I pulled the light and see there is a black cable and a red wire. I ran a new cable for the ceiling that has white and black and neutral. I want to keep the outlet always hot and I also bought a new 15 amp single pole switch. My problem is the red wire, Do I connected that to the white wire? Also how can I make my outlet hot?
Thank you. [image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?  Also, is the box a fan-rated type?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added the picture above

Comment: I figured it out. The orange cables I connected to the white cable.

Comment: What do you mean by "orange cables"?

Comment: The orange colored cables next to the single red one, were the cables I connected the white cable from the new wires I ran and it worked. I was told that those orange cables were used instead of white long time ago. I connected the red single wire to the bunch of black wires to run keep my outlet hot and from the bunch of black wires connected it to the common on the light switch.

Comment: The 'orange colored cables' are bare copper and are the ground wires. You should not be connecting them to the neutral wires (the white-coated ones).